# Service Thread Dies on Start

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to run continuous voice recognition service in the background of android application. I want the service to send the processed text back to main thread for UI purposes.

When I'm in the run function of my thread, the thread dies immediately after binding the service. Can any of you guys guide me in the right direction as to why this is happening?

Here is the service code borrowed from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/speech/RecognitionService.java#40)

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 * use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
 * the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */

package com.example.quadcontrol;

//import android.annotation.SdkConstant;
//import android.annotation.SdkConstant.SdkConstantType;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.speech.RecognitionListener;
import android.speech.RecognitionService;
import android.speech.SpeechRecognizer;
import android.util.Log;



public abstract class SimpleVoiceService extends Service 
{   
    /**
     * The {@link Intent} that must be declared as handled by the service.
     */
    //@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.SERVICE_ACTION)
    public static final String SERVICE_INTERFACE = "android.speech.RecognitionService";

    /**
     * Name under which a RecognitionService component publishes information about itself.
     * This meta-data should reference an XML resource containing a
     * <code>&lt;{@link android.R.styleable#RecognitionService recognition-service}&gt;</code> tag.
     */
    public static final String SERVICE_META_DATA = "android.speech";

    /** Log messages identifier */
    private static final String TAG = "SimpleVoiceService";

    /** Debugging flag */
    private static final boolean DBG = false;

    /** Binder of the recognition service */
    private RecognitionServiceBinder mBinder = new RecognitionServiceBinder(this);

    /**
     * The current callback of an application that invoked the
     * {@link RecognitionService#onStartListening(Intent, Callback)} method
     */
    private Callback mCurrentCallback = null;

    private static final int MSG_START_LISTENING = 1;

    private static final int MSG_STOP_LISTENING = 2;

    private static final int MSG_CANCEL = 3;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_START_LISTENING:
                    StartListeningArgs args = (StartListeningArgs) msg.obj;
                    dispatchStartListening(args.mIntent, args.mListener);
                    break;
                case MSG_STOP_LISTENING:
                    dispatchStopListening((RecognitionListener) msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MSG_CANCEL:
                    dispatchCancel((RecognitionListener) msg.obj);
            }
        }
    };

    private void dispatchStartListening(Intent intent, android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback mListener) {
        if (mCurrentCallback == null) {
            //if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "created new mCurrentCallback, listener = " + mListener.asBinder());
            mCurrentCallback = new Callback(mListener);
            SimpleVoiceService.this.onStartListening(intent, mCurrentCallback);
        } else {
            try {
                mListener.error(SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onError call from startListening failed");
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "concurrent startListening received - ignoring this call");
        }
    }

    private void dispatchStopListening(RecognitionListener listener) {
        if (mCurrentCallback == null) {
            listener.onError(SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT);
            Log.w(TAG, "stopListening called with no preceding startListening - ignoring");
        } else if (mCurrentCallback.mListener != listener) {
            listener.onError(SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY);
            Log.w(TAG, "stopListening called by other caller than startListening - ignoring");
        } else { // the correct state
            SimpleVoiceService.this.onStopListening(mCurrentCallback);
        }
    }

    private void dispatchCancel(RecognitionListener listener) {
        if (mCurrentCallback == null) {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "cancel called with no preceding startListening - ignoring");
        } else if (mCurrentCallback.mListener != listener) {
            Log.w(TAG, "cancel called by client who did not call startListening - ignoring");
        } else { // the correct state
            SimpleVoiceService.this.onCancel(mCurrentCallback);
            mCurrentCallback = null;
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "canceling - setting mCurrentCallback to null");
        }
    }

    private class StartListeningArgs {
        public final Intent mIntent;

        public final android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback mListener;

        public StartListeningArgs(Intent intent, android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback listener) {
            this.mIntent = intent;
            this.mListener = listener;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the caller has sufficient permissions
     * 
     * @param listener to send the error message to in case of error
     * @return {@code true} if the caller has enough permissions, {@code false} otherwise
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions(android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback listener) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions");
        if (SimpleVoiceService.this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.
                RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "call for recognition service without RECORD_AUDIO permissions");
        try {
            listener.error(SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Notifies the service that it should start listening for speech.
     * 
     * @param recognizerIntent contains parameters for the recognition to be performed. The intent
     *        may also contain optional extras, see {@link RecognizerIntent}. If these values are
     *        not set explicitly, default values should be used by the recognizer.
     * @param listener that will receive the service's callbacks
     */
    protected abstract void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener);

    /**
     * Notifies the service that it should cancel the speech recognition.
     */
    protected abstract void onCancel(Callback listener);

    /**
     * Notifies the service that it should stop listening for speech. Speech captured so far should
     * be recognized as if the user had stopped speaking at this point. This method is only called
     * if the application calls it explicitly.
     */
    protected abstract void onStopListening(Callback listener);

    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onBind, intent=" + intent);
        return (IBinder) mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mCurrentCallback = null;
        mBinder.clearReference();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * This class receives callbacks from the speech recognition service and forwards them to the
     * user. An instance of this class is passed to the
     * {@link RecognitionService#onStartListening(Intent, Callback)} method. Recognizers may call
     * these methods on any thread.
     */
    public class Callback {
        private final android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback mListener;

        private Callback(android.speech.RecognitionService.Callback mListener2) {
            mListener = mListener2;
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when the user has started to speak.
         */
        public void beginningOfSpeech() throws RemoteException {
            if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "beginningOfSpeech");
            mListener.beginningOfSpeech();
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when sound has been received. The purpose of this
         * function is to allow giving feedback to the user regarding the captured audio.
         * 
         * @param buffer a buffer containing a sequence of big-endian 16-bit integers representing a
         *        single channel audio stream. The sample rate is implementation dependent.
         */
        public void bufferReceived(byte[] buffer) throws RemoteException {
            mListener.bufferReceived(buffer);
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method after the user stops speaking.
         */
        public void endOfSpeech() throws RemoteException {
            mListener.endOfSpeech();
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when a network or recognition error occurred.
         * 
         * @param error code is defined in {@link SpeechRecognizer}
         */
        public void error(int error) throws RemoteException {
            mCurrentCallback = null;
            mListener.error(error);
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when partial recognition results are available. This
         * method can be called at any time between {@link #beginningOfSpeech()} and
         * {@link #results(Bundle)} when partial results are ready. This method may be called zero,
         * one or multiple times for each call to {@link SpeechRecognizer#startListening(Intent)},
         * depending on the speech recognition service implementation.
         * 
         * @param partialResults the returned results. To retrieve the results in
         *        ArrayList&lt;String&gt; format use {@link Bundle#getStringArrayList(String)} with
         *        {@link SpeechRecognizer#RESULTS_RECOGNITION} as a parameter
         */
        public void partialResults(Bundle partialResults) throws RemoteException {
            mListener.partialResults(partialResults);
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when the endpointer is ready for the user to start
         * speaking.
         * 
         * @param params parameters set by the recognition service. Reserved for future use.
         */
        public void readyForSpeech(Bundle params) throws RemoteException {
            mListener.readyForSpeech(params);
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when recognition results are ready.
         * 
         * @param results the recognition results. To retrieve the results in {@code
         *        ArrayList&lt;String&gt;} format use {@link Bundle#getStringArrayList(String)} with
         *        {@link SpeechRecognizer#RESULTS_RECOGNITION} as a parameter
         */
        public void results(Bundle results) throws RemoteException {
            mCurrentCallback = null;
            mListener.results(results);
        }

        /**
         * The service should call this method when the sound level in the audio stream has changed.
         * There is no guarantee that this method will be called.
         * 
         * @param rmsdB the new RMS dB value
         */
        public void rmsChanged(float rmsdB) throws RemoteException {
            mListener.rmsChanged(rmsdB);
        }
    }

    /** Binder of the recognition service */
    private static class RecognitionServiceBinder extends RecognitionService {
        private SimpleVoiceService mInternalService;

        public RecognitionServiceBinder(SimpleVoiceService simpleVoiceService) {
            mInternalService = simpleVoiceService;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStartListening(Intent recognizerIntent, Callback listener) {
            //if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "startListening called by:" + listener.asBinder());
            if (mInternalService != null && mInternalService.checkPermissions(listener)) {
                mInternalService.mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mInternalService.mHandler,
                        MSG_START_LISTENING, mInternalService.new StartListeningArgs(
                                recognizerIntent, listener)));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStopListening(Callback listener) {
            //if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "stopListening called by:" + listener.asBinder());
            if (mInternalService != null && mInternalService.checkPermissions(listener)) {
                mInternalService.mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mInternalService.mHandler,
                        MSG_STOP_LISTENING, listener));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancel(Callback listener) {
            //if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "cancel called by:" + listener.asBinder());
            if (mInternalService != null && mInternalService.checkPermissions(listener)) {
                mInternalService.mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mInternalService.mHandler,
                        MSG_CANCEL, listener));
            }
        }

        public void clearReference() {
            mInternalService = null;
        }    
    }
}
```

Here is my MainActivity

```Java
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Activity";
    private TextView txtMsg;    // TextView that shows the number
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_info);
        final ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
        {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

        Thread t = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                //Start service
                getApplicationContext().bindService(
                            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleVoiceService.class), 
                            serviceConnection,
                            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

            }
        };

        t.start();

        //Create handler for receiving messages
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage)
            {
                //switch(inputMessage.what)
                //{
                    //case 4:
                    //{
                        txtMsg.setText((String)inputMessage.obj);
                        //break;
                    //}             
                //}
            }
        };

        //mHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, 1));
        txtMsg.setText("Service Started");
    }
```

Here is my Manifest (This is a Google glass project)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.quadcontrol"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:immersive="true" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >                      

             <intent-filter>                
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />               
            </intent-filter>

              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="com.google.angroid.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />    
        </activity>

        <recognition-service
            android:name="WordService" 
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/service_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </recognition-service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: When you say *"the thread dies immediately after binding the service"*, is there an exception, stack trace on the logs?

Comment: On second thought..the thread would die whenever its done binding the service, correct? If so, then I'm afraid I'm asking the wrong question :/

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Look in your adb logcat

Comment: Hey, Ok. Sorry for the long wait I got busy with school for a sec, but in logcat the Activity Manager says "Unable to start service Intent {...} U=0: not found". I'm going to look into this as well..

Comment: It looks like it cannot find your service. Maybe because the class `SimpleVoiceService ` is abstract? Maybe try to remove the `abstract` keyword, or bind to another non-abstract service that extends this one.

Comment: @Janos Wow, you're right! I added a class to extend the abstract service, but now I have to figure out what I should put in my onStartListening, ... methods....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say:

> the thread dies immediately after binding the service

I expect there would be an exception with stack trace in your logs. That would probably shed more light to what's really going on.

---

On a closer look, the service class you specified is abstract....

> ```
> public abstract class SimpleVoiceService extends Service
> ```

I don't have an Android development environment with me right now to confirm this, but I'm not sure this can work this way. Either remove the `abstract` modifier, or bind to another non-abstract service that extends this one.

---

Also, why bind to the service in a thread? Instead of this:

> ```
> Thread t = new Thread()
> {
>     public void run()
>     {
>         //Start service
>         getApplicationContext().bindService(
>                     new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleVoiceService.class), 
>                     serviceConnection,
>                     Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
>
>     }
> };
> t.start();
> ```

Why don't you do it simply this way:

```
getApplicationContext().bindService(
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SimpleVoiceService.class), 
            serviceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: See comments in question.